# How can I create a density plot (using as a reference a histogram)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following script

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig5 = plt.figure()
fig5.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.4, hspace=0.6)
ax5_2 = fig5.add_subplot(212)
std_error = "{:.2f}".format(np.std(df['error']))
ave_error = "{:.2f}".format(np.nanmean(df['error']))
ax5_2.set_title("Error Histogram ave:" + ave_error + " std:" + std_error)
ax5_2.hist(df['error'], range=(0, 2), bins=20)
```

with that I get

[image]

I want to plot the density here.
I tried

```
hist,bin_edges=np.histogram(df['error'], range=(0, 2), bins=20,density=True)
bin_widths=np.diff(bin_edges)
densities = hist / (np.sum(hist) * bin_widths)
plt.bar(bin_edges[:-1], densities, width=bin_widths, align='edge')

# Customize your plot as needed
plt.xlabel('X-axis Label')
plt.ylabel('Density')
plt.title('Density Plot')
```

with that I got

[image]

Is this correct?
And second, I thought density plots were smooth line-like plots and not bars.

How can I create the density plot corresponding to the histogram above?

(I tried seaborn completely unrelated histograms and density plots...)

EDIT:
I tried mcgusty solution

```
errors = np.random.randn(100)
df = pd.DataFrame({'errors': errors})
sns.histplot(data=df, x="errors", kde=True)
```

and I got

[image]

but then I tried the equivalent in matplotlib

```
fig5 = plt.figure()
fig5.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.4, hspace=0.6)
ax5_2 = fig5.add_subplot(212)
ax5_2.hist(errors, range=(-3, 3), bins=9)
```

and I got
[image]
and

```
hist,bin_edges=np.histogram(errors, range=(-3, 3), bins=9,density=True)
bin_widths=np.diff(bin_edges)
densities = hist / (np.sum(hist) * bin_widths)
plt.bar(bin_edges[:-1], densities, width=bin_widths, align='edge')
```

[image]

Quite different!

Comment: [`sns.histplot(data=errors, bins=10, kde=True)`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vK9o.png) produces the same histogram bars as [`plt.hist(errors, bins=10, ec='k')`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9JcM.png). If you want density in seaborn, you have to specify that, [`sns.histplot(data=errors, bins=10, kde=True, stat='density')`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97m3m.png).

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney I did what you indicated. Yes sns produced the same histogram as plt, and then I could get the density with sns. The final question is, how can I get this same last density with plt?

Comment: If you look at [`plt.hist`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html), you'll see that it has a Boolean `density` parameter. The docs show the relevant calculation that's used. The duplicate shows how to calculate the curve.

Answer (score 0):

I think using [seaborn.histplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html#seaborn.histplot) can help in adding a density-plot over the bars.

Something like this should probably work:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

errors = np.random.randn(100)
df = pd.DataFrame({'errors': errors})
sns.histplot(data=df, x="errors", kde=True)
```

Comment: I tried your solution but the results were quite different (see EDIT)